# Celery + HaProxy + RabbitMQ lose task messages

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

Probably not the best place to ask (maybe Server Fault), but I'd try here:

I have django celery sending tasks via HaProxy to a RabbitMQ cluster, and we are losing messages (tasks not being executed) every now and then.

**Observed**

- We turned of the workers and monitored the queue size, we noticed that we started 100 jobs but only 99 showed up in the queue.
- It seems to happen when other processes are using RabbitMQ for other jobs

**Tried**

- I tried flooding RabbitMQ with dummy messages with many connections and tried to put some proper tasks in to the queue, I couldn't replicate the issue constantly.

Just wondering if anyone had experienced this before?

**UPDATE:**

So I dove into the code and eventually stumble on to celery/app/amqp.py, I was debugging by adding extra publish method to an non-existing exchange, see below:

```
    log.warning(111111111)
    self.publish(
        body,
        exchange=exchange, routing_key=routing_key,
        serializer=serializer or self.serializer,
        compression=compression or self.compression,
        headers=headers,
        retry=retry, retry_policy=_rp,
        reply_to=reply_to,
        correlation_id=task_id,
        delivery_mode=delivery_mode, declare=declare,
        **kwargs
    )
    log.warning(222222222)

    self.publish(
        body,
        exchange='celery2', routing_key='celery1',
        serializer=serializer or self.serializer,
        compression=compression or self.compression,
        headers=headers,
        retry=retry, retry_policy=_rp,
        reply_to=reply_to,
        correlation_id=task_id,
        delivery_mode=delivery_mode, declare=declare,
        **kwargs
    )
    log.warning(333333333)
```

Then tried to trigger 100 tasks from project code, and then result was only 1 message got put into the celery queue, I think it's caused by ProducerPool or ConnectionPool

Comment: From the documentation, CELERY_ACKS_LATE¶
Late ack means the task messages will be acknowledged after the task has been executed, not just before, which is the default behavior.

Comment: I meant with RMQ - consumers can use acknowledgements to confirm when a job is completed, or negative acknowledgements to reject a job and push it back onto the work queue. Without these, jobs may be silently dropped if the consumer fails without completing the job. I don't know Celery at all, but making sure that RMQ consumers use acks prevents jobs from being lost.

Comment: @ChrisHeald I updated my question, problem is messages are not being put into the queue.

Comment: Sounds like the issue may be with HAProxy? Have you tried eliminating HAProxy from the stack to see if the issue persists?

Comment: Tried to point to the rabbitmq servers directly, problem still exists.

Comment: When you queue your messages, try setting the `mandatory` flag, if possible. http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.publish and check the return of your publish call to be sure that an exception isn't being thrown and silently swallowed.

Comment: Tried that also, no luck. I can be sure that no exception has been raised since it's logging the next line of code and no try catch around them.

Comment: Have you tried using [publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)? If RMQ confirms that the message is queued, then you should be able to rely on that. Perhaps your RMQ library is failing to queue the item, but not throwing an exception?